# Installing Ubuntu restart error (I'm a noob)

Tags: boot, grub2

I have limited experience with installing OS's, being that I've only played around with Windows XP many years ago.

So, I created the image on usb and it appeared that Ubuntu installed successfully. The install process then required me to restart to complete installation. Which I did.

Upon restart there was prompt displaying the below;

```
[  3.667475] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1
[  3.667482] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[ 13.034441] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: preinit failed with -22
[ 13.034487] nouveau DRM:00000000:00000080: init failed with -22
```

I wasn't sure what to do (I'm hoping my next action didn't ruin the install), so I restarted the machine.

Upon startup there was a prompt with a few options though I selected the first to load Ubuntu (I think), though now whenever I try to boot Ubuntu it directs me to the grub prompt screen.

I've had a look at the directories available and there is only 1 that says the filesystem is FAT...

So, I need help!?!?! Greatly appreciate any responses & assistance for this.

thanks.

Comment: this is Ubuntu version 16.04.02 and using grub2

Comment: Sorry a bit more info, I'm installing Ubuntu to operate in parallel with Windows 10 64bit version.

Comment: Did you try running the install media in the "try Ubuntu" mode?  Is this a UEFI machine with Windows 10 installed in UEFI mode?  If you have Nvidia hardware, did you try the "nomodeset" option on the kernel boot line (edit grub boot screen, assuming UEFI, add word after "quiet splash")?

Comment: hi, yes I tried ubuntu first which ran successfully and yes it is UEFI, i also turned off 'turn on fast startup'. Yes my laptop is an HP omen that has a GForce GTX 960m graphics card...I can try your above command though you might have to dumb it down for me as Im not sure how to execute your command? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't an answer though currently I'm writing this in my Ubuntu instance. I have no idea what went wrong, all I did was log into Windows, wrote my question, logged back out about an hour later and tried to re-launch Ubuntu to which now it has initiated successfully and I'm able to use.

Thanks -